# Ecommerce credit card integration

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, credit-card

I am aware of some third-party online payment processor. However, I've seen some sites who doesn't state which payment processor they use (eg. PayPal), the only field I see are registration details and credit card information fields. What are these type of payment processors?

Example, in [Linode](https://manager.linode.com/signup/) I wonder what they use as a credit card processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called Payment Gateways.  They generally come with an api.  You connect, send the CC details, payment is processed, response is sent back.

A popular gateway in New Zealand is DPS.
http://www.paymentexpress.com/

They are incredibly easy to use and have different options depending on the size of your operation.

Comment: Thanks for this. So does this says it is country/region specific?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, if you are required to have a merchant account with a bank then I imagine you would need your Payment Gateway to have accounts in that country too.